# Java Graphic trouble when shooting multiple bullet

Tags: java, graphic

So i'm trying to create this java game about aircraft shooting aliens and stuff. The aircraft shoot a bullet every time mouse click. That mean the aircraft can shoot 10 or 20 or more bullets at a time. To demonstrate the bullet movement i tried Thread and Timer but the real problem is if i 1 bullet shot out that mean i created a new Thread(or Timer) and that make the game run very slow. Is there any way i can fix this problem?
Here a my code for bullet moving

```
public class Bullet extends JComponent implements Runnable {

int x;//coordinates
int y;
BufferedImage img = null;
Thread thr;
public Bullet(int a, int b) {
        x = a;
        y = b;
        thr = new Thread(this);
        thr.start();

    }
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            img = ImageIO.read(new File("bullet.png"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // g.drawImage(resizeImage(img, 2), x, y, this);

        g.drawImage(Plane.scale(img, 2, img.getWidth(), img.getHeight(), 0.125, 0.125), x, y, this);
        width = img.getWidth() / 8;
        height = img.getHeight() / 8;

        super.paintComponent(g);

    }
public void run() {


        while(true)
        {
            if(y<-50)break;//if the bullet isnt out of the frame yet
            y-=5;//move up
            repaint();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Create a Bullet class that contains the x, y position of the bullet.  Create an instance of Bullet for each bullet fired.  Keep the instances of Bullet in a List.  Create **one** thread to update the positions of the bullet and draw the bullets on the  screen by iterating through the List of Bullet objects.  Get the reading of the bullet image out of the paintComponent method.  Call super.paintComponent first.  Hire a tutor to teach you proper Java Swing coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bullet should NOT be on its own thread. There are several reasons for this, one of which is the one you mentioned - it is going to make your game very slow.

Try using one master thread which updates all bullets. You will need an update function in your bullet:

```
public class Bullet extends JComponent {
 public void update() {
  if(y<-50)return; //if the bullet isnt out of the frame yet
  y-=5;           //move up
 }

 //all your other code for your bullet
}
```

Then in your master thread have a list of bullets:

```
LinkedList<Bullet> bullets = new LinkedList<>();
```

In the run method of that thread, you can continuously update ALL bullets:

```
public void run() {
    while(true)
    {
        for (Bullet b : bullets) {
            b.update();
        }
        repaint();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

You will need to have a method in your master thread that lets you add a new bullet:

```
public void addBullet(Bullet b) {
    bullets.add(b);
}
```

Then you can call that to add a new bullet and the master thread will update that bullet along with all the others.

Comment: If my answer helped it would be great if you upvoted and / or accepted it.